# struts2 request encoding

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, struts2, request

I am sending a XML in HTTP POST body.

Question:

1. Does struts2 support processing request in utf-8 encoding?

Reference:

- http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/Q_24061148.html

(Around bottom of the page)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you shouldn't have any problem, just define the enconding in your action when sending the stream to the view, in case you are using the stream result type.

```
STRUTS.XML
<result name="xml" type="stream">
<param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
</result>

ACTION
setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlObject.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
return "xml";
```